# Looping through files of specific type in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

Recently upgraded from Win7 to Win10, so the only command-line program I can now easily open from a folder is PowerShell, rather than the command prompt. I used to quite frequently use this in Command Prompt:

`for %F in (*.mp4) do (ffmpeg -i %F %~nF.avi)`

But in PowerShell, that's a no-go. What's the equivalent syntax here? All I can figure out by Googling is that I should probably be using a foreach loop not a for loop, but even then I still haven't the foggiest how to define the list of files, or what the equivalents of %F and %~nF are, if they exist, or...

Comment: What do you mean by "*so the only command-line program I can now easily open from a folder is PowerShell, rather than the command prompt*"? You know you can set up having the CMD available on a right click, don't you?  

Comment: You still can open CMD, but in case you want to use PS, you can do semthing like:

$files = Get-ChildItem *.mp4

foreach ($file in $files) {
    $outputFileName = "{0}.avi" -f $file.BaseName
    ffmpeg -i $file.FullName $outputFileName
}

Answer (score 0):

I would go for this. It may require some tuning based on your actual situation

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "path to folder" -Filter "*.mp4" -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    Start-Process "ffmpeg -i $($_.FullName) $($_.BaseName).avi"
}
```

Comment: put it in a function for future use. That's much simpler in powershell. Besides in powershell there's persistent history so it's far more convenient

Comment: I am not sure that `-Recurse` should be used.

Comment: @lit not sure neither..... Up to koberulz to tune accordingly his situation

Comment: Why is the argument to start-process single quoted?

Comment: @WalterMitty, Indeed, double quote should be better to handle the $

Answer (score 0):

Looping in Powershell is more flexible than it was in CMD, but there is a longer learning curve.

If you want to learn looping in powershell,  use your browser to visit "about_foreach"  or "foreach-object".  This will give you the online copy of the help topics for two different ways to do looping in PS.  All the help topics are available within PS, and they are also available in your browser if you know what to search for.

If you just want a quick solution to your current problem in PS,  @civette has given you an excellent start.  Or you can try this:

```
foreach ($file in (get-childitem *.mp4)) {
    $basename = $_.basename
    & ffmpeg -i $file $basename.avi
    }
```

If you really just want to use CMD, and you can only start powershell,  try entering the "cmd" command at the powershell prompt.